# How to use the pushbutton without using if, else

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to let the led blink for 3 seconds then 2 seconds then one second using the button one time and without using if/else

```
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once: 
    pinMode(5, INPUT); 
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
} 

void loop() { 
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly: 
    digitalRead(5, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH); 
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH); 
    delay(2000); 
    digitalWrite(6, LOW); 
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH); 
    delay(1000); 
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use if/else? Or is this a school assignment?

Comment: it is a school assignment actually

Comment: `switch case` is your friend ;)

Comment: Switch is an alternative to if --- unless are you at the "interrupts" section of your class...

Comment: `digitalRead()` returns either `LOW` (which is a macro equivalent to `0`) or `HIGH` (which is `1`).

Comment: I can think of a dozen ways to write what you want.  None of them are very good, the best method would use an if statement.  The problem is that the teacher probably wants you to use some skill that you just learned and we don't know what that is.  I could write you a great program that doesn't use an if statement, but if it isn't what your teacher is looking for then you probably still wont' get credit for the assignment and you'll make it readily apparent that you have people on the internet doing your homework for you, which if your teacher is any good at all get you kicked out of class.

Comment: @GMc `delay` doesn't work when put inside interrupt method, because itself it uses interrupts to increase the millis timer counter. The only way of writing this logic with interrupts is to set a flag in global scope and then use `if` to test for that flag in `loop` method. So interrupts are not the good solution to this homework. Unless maybe make button press interrupt to setup timer interrupt? That seems really awful..

Comment: @FilipFranik I agree and did not advocate that. You definitely don't want to include any lengthy operations in an interrupt service routine. My comment was more of a suggestion that switch is an obvious alternative to using an if - but it is also possible that the OP was at the "interrupts" section of their class and thus would require a completely different approach to the serial code as posted in the question - and as you suggest, definitely should not be using delay. Hopefully that was also taught in the class... I should perhaps in hindsight been more clear in my original comment.

Comment: was that a 'cut-and-pasto' with 'digitalRead(5, HIGH);'?  The digitalRead() function only takes one argument, not 2.

Comment: And, while I'm on the subject, some comments about good coding style.  Try to avoid using 'magic numbers' in your code.  Statements like 'digitalWrite(6,HIGH)' should be replaced by something like 'digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH), where LED_PIN is defined before setup() with something like '#define LED_PIN 6' or 'const int LED_PIN = 6;' (which one you use here is more a matter of style than anything else).  Also explanatory comments should be used liberally; they will tend to make you think about what it is you are trying to do and will help reviewers like us to understand your intent.

Answer (score 1):

As the required operation is finite and short, you can just hard code the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You could you simple inversion of boolean variable to set state of LED.

```
const int LedPin = 5;
bool ledState = true;

// in your loop

// bool will be transformed from true to 1 (HIGH)
digitalWrite(LedPin, (int)ledState);
// invert LED state to be false
ledState = !ledState;
// false -> 0 (LOW)
digitalWrite(LedPin, (int)ledState);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator maybe helpful. [[Reference]](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/arduino/arduino_conditional_operator.htm)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.